# Efficiency of join table or join select * from table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Given this scenario in Oracle SQL

```
    select * from a join b;
```

vs

```
    select * from a join (select * from b);
```

vs

```
    select * from a join (select col1 from b);
```

assume in the last scenario there are at least 5 columns in b.

In this kind of situation would it be faster to join directly or faster to join through a select?

What if the join with a select is not selecting all the columns but a tiny portion of them.

P.S. please excuse the pseudocode.

Comment: There is no SQL platform that does not let you look at the execution plan.  You can just look at the execution plan and see that the first two cross joins are exactly the same.  Dumb to perform a cross join, it will be very slow and is rarely needed.  But the same.

Comment: You are neglecting to specify the join columns, for example, if you are joining to B on col1, and selecting col2, and you have an index on col1, col2, then Oracle will only read the index. If including all column data from table B then the table will have to be read which of course will be more expensive. On a cross join, even if the column being selected is indexed, Oracle will still do a full table scan as the index will not include nulls that must be included in the cross join. When in doubt - EXPLAIN PLAN is your friend!

Comment: @MichaelBroughton - if there are no join columns then these are cross joins.  Why assume the user does not want cross joins?

Comment: @Hogan - cross joins are uncommon, and we're being shown pseudocode. As such, I opted for some additional clarity in case it was relevant

Comment: @Hogan - lol, point taken.

Comment: My mistake at not being clear, there are certainly join columns, I just didn't want to make the example too complex.

That being said, I've seen the explain plan for the first 2 queries, they're the same. But the performance is not. The first query runs significantly faster than the second one.

Comment: One may have simply optimized for the first rows and the second for all rows. If they have the same plan then they should require the same execution time to fetch all of the data.

Comment: That is what I was expecting, but it did not behave that way. Which is what prompted me to ask this question, as the explain plans were exactly the same (with a few naming differences) but the actual run time was not, in fact they were significantly different.

Comment: Interesting -- I'd expect the same plan to run the same.  Is the difference really "significant" and are the plans **exactly** the same?  If this is really your question please post the plans and the testing methodology and the testing results -- then we will be able to tell you why.

Comment: I appreciate you both for the contributions, it looks like the general consensus here is that they should run identically. I'm not sure why it's not performing as such, but fortunately that is not a huge concern as there will never be a need to run a join (select * ...). My main concern is regarding how the join would work given limited selections from the second table. After running a few sample from Nates example it looks like the runtime and explain for joining as such is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your first and second options are going to be doing the exact same thing under the hood.  You might actually lose out on some internal optimization by doing the join (select * from b) method.

Presuming your b table has a large amount of data in it, selecting a subset of that data would optimize performance.  This would probably be due to the fact that you are using `select *` on the outer query, which would in turn, grab all columns from the join if you did not limit said join.  Now suppose a fourth option:

```
select a.*, b.col1 from a join b;
```

It would be interesting to find out if the above is more or less optimal than:

```
select * from a join (select col1 from b);
```

Pure conjecture at this point, but I would guess that the second may be better, since it reduces the amount of data being returned in the subquery so essentially.. it would reduce the dataset earlier in the process of producing your result.

Comment: I've ran the explain plan for both, and again they're identical. Fortunately unlike the regular join on select * , the two queries ran in similar time.

Comment: "since it reduces the amount of data being returned in the subquery so essentially" Except Oracle doesn't have to return data from the subquery if it isn't used later.

Comment: My use of the word 'returned' is really intended to mean for internal usage, not that it is producing the data as output.  Basically, internally, it has less data to work on thus, it should reduce ram / cpu cycles.  Again, that is in the section 'pure conjecture at this point', and I was pontificating to some extent =)

Comment: Thanks to you both, my main concern here was how Oracle would handle this specific situation that you listed out. After running some test cases and explain plans, the data here does indeed look good, in fact much better than select * from b which we would expect.

Comment: Glad to hear you got what you needed!

Answer (score 2):

First two are the exact same thing, unless you mean compare against a complex query. And in that case

this

```
 select * from a join (select * from b where col1 = 1);
```

is equal to this

```
select * from a join b
where b.col1 = 1;
```

Last query

```
select * from a join (select col1 from b);
```

Usually the problem isnt the

```
 (select col1 from b)
```

The problem is use `*` on the first select, just reduce the number of fields to the minimun you need to improve performance.

```
 select * from a ....
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I understand that the first two are equivalent, what I'm more interested in is whether one way runs faster than the other.

Running one the first query I can achieve a select first 50 rows in under 5 seconds, while running the second query achieve the same 50 rows in 60 seconds. I'm unsure as to what causes the discrepancy. Especially considering I ran the 5 second query first so the second time it should have been cached.

Comment: should be the same, but the only way to be sure is using `EXPLAIN PLAN`

Comment: Edited first comment.

Also the explain plan for the first 2 queries are identical with a few naming differences.

Comment: If you are already running the query why use pseudo code? Still you should provide the `EXPLAIN PLAN`, so we can compare it and tell you what is happening.